# What does "stage a vote" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a news on BBC and there's a sentence I can't understand its meaning:

*Nancy Pelosi, Democratic leader in the House of Representatives, tried on Tuesday **to stage a symbolic vote** to support the findings of Russian interference, but was blocked by Republicans.*
(https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-44870835)

Could you explain what the bold part means please?

Comment: Just a personal opinion, but to me at least, the cited use of ***stage*** is relatively "marked", since in this exact context I'd normally expect ***force*** (or perhaps some more "neutral" term such as ***hold, get, organise***). Using ***stage*** here carries strong connotations of "theatrics", as echoed a couple of lines further into the piece, where the proposed symbolic vote is described as ***just some messaging exercise***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much for detailed opinion, especially giving alternatives!

Answer (score 1):

[to stage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stage) in the sense of:

> - to plan, organize, or carry out (an activity), especially for dramatic or public effect:
>     *Workers staged a one-day strike.*

From [Time](http://time.com/5341795/president-trump-russia-putin-summit-criticism/):

> - In the House, Democratic leader Nancy Pelosi staged a vote in support of the intelligence committee’s findings that Russia interfered in the 2016 election. But even that largely symbolic measure was blocked party-line by Republican

Comment: You might want to add a [*sic*] after *party-line*. (I checked the article online to confirm that it was actually written that way—as opposed to *along party lines*.) Oh, and add an *s.* at the end of the quote. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much user070221 and @Jason Bassford! May I ask one more please? Does 'stage a vote' mean the same with 'vote on', 'take a vote on', or 'put sth to the vote?'